# Convert all columns in list of data frames to time series

Tags: r, list, time-series, lapply

I have such a list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2 = 6:10)
rownames(df1) <- 2001:2005
df2 <- data.frame(var5 = 21:25, var6 = 26:30)
rownames(df2) <- 2006:2010
mylist <- list(df1,df2)

> mylist
[[1]]
     var1 var2
2001    1    6
2002    2    7
2003    3    8
2004    4    9
2005    5   10

[[2]]
     var5 var6
2006   21   26
2007   22   27
2008   23   28
2009   24   29
2010   25   30
```

How can I convert each column within each data frame to a time series where start and end are given by min and max of the rownames of the respective data frame?

I tried:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) {apply(x, 2, function(y) ts(y, start = min(rownames(y), end = max(rownames(y)))))})
```

resulting in:

```
 Error in if (nobs != ndata) data <- if (NCOL(data) == 1) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

but fail to make any sense of that.

Comment: I think you forgot to close a bracket after `start=min(rownames(y)`.
Try `lapply(mylist, function(x) {apply(x, 2, function(y) ts(y, start = min(rownames(y)), end = max(rownames(y))))})`.

And I'm not sure but maybe in `max` and `min` functions you should do `as.numeric(rownames(y))`. Because `rownames(y)` will give you strings and R can not calculate min or max of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this by looping columns using `lapply` instead of `apply` as the output of `apply` is a `matrix` and all the class gets lost.  In addition, `min/max` works on `numeric/integer` elements, so it is advisable to convert the `character` class of `row.names` to `numeric`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) ts(y, 
      start = min(as.numeric(row.names(x))), end = max(as.numeric(row.names(x))))))
lst1[[1]][[1]]
#Time Series:
#Start = 2001 
#End = 2005 
#Frequency = 1 
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

---

If we need to create `ts` as columns, then assign the output back to the data.frame to keep the structure as before

```
 lst2 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {
       x[] <- lapply(x, function(y) ts(y, start = min(as.numeric(row.names(x))),
                     end = max(as.numeric(row.names(x)))))
         x})
 str(lst2)
 #List of 2
 #$ :'data.frame':       5 obs. of  2 variables:
 # ..$ var1: Time-Series [1:5] from 2001 to 2005: 1 2 3 4 5
 # ..$ var2: Time-Series [1:5] from 2001 to 2005: 6 7 8 9 10
 #$ :'data.frame':       5 obs. of  2 variables:
 # ..$ var5: Time-Series [1:5] from 2006 to 2010: 21 22 23 24 25
 # ..$ var6: Time-Series [1:5] from 2006 to 2010: 26 27 28 29 30
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to avoid that sub lists are created? I'd like to keep the structure with a list of data frames with one column per series

Comment: @beetroot That you can do with `xts` i.e. `lst3 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) xts(x, order.by = as.Date(sprintf("%s-01-01", row.names(x))))); class(lst3[[1]])#
[1] "xts" "zoo"`

Comment: Yeah the whole question was pretty stupid as I don't need to do anything by column. I was confused ;) Thanks anyway